# WebAPI service not being called from .js file in MVC 4 project

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my WebApi MVC 4 Project, the call in the script is as :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var x = 4;
    var y = 0;
    iAlertHis('<%=ResolveUrl("~/") %>');
});
```

the .js file looks like :

```
function iAlertHis(_url) { 
    $.GetJSON("_url"+"api/History/", function(){});
}
```

The routing is as follows:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( name: "DefaultApi",
                                    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/",
                                    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

and the controller is as :

```
public class HistoryController : ApiController
{
    public string GetialertHist() {

        BALiAlert objBALiAlert = new BALiAlert();

        JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string Json = oSerializer.Serialize(objBALiAlert.ialertHist());
        return Json;
   }
```

}

Running the project gives the error on the call:  `$.GetJSON(_url+"api/History",function(){});`

```
'Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is a case sensitive language. And jquery has no method `$.GetJSON`. But there is a method [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

Besides, regularly you will not find any js function/property starting with uppercase letter. Usually first letter is lowercase.